# Installing Pop OS on a system having two Hard-disks

Tags: partition, system-installation, pop-os

I want to change from Windows to Pop OS, I don't want to make a partition and getting a dual boot, just want to say goodbye to Windows, the issue is that I'm not pretty sure if doing this having two Hard-disks (128GB+1TB), so, is it possible that I loose one Hard-disk on the process ? I'm worried to loose the 1TB Hard-disk (currently I'm working on my local C drive (the one of 128GB, so don't know if I can loose the 1TB of storage).

Comment: Is there any data on any of the 2 disks you will need? What do you  mean by lose? Do you mean losing the data on it or not being able to use it from Pop os?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 128G is your faster SSD, where currently your Windows System is installed?

You can install whatever on your 128GB without losing any data on your 1TB. The only problem afterwards is, that Linux Systems are not made for interacting with **ntfs** (Windows Filesystem) - or I should say, they can read/write but as it is not a native Linux Filesystem, it's rather slow and not well supported.

1. backup all the data from the 1TB
2. install PopOS on the 128GB
3. format 1TB to a Linux Filesystem like `xfs, ext4, btrfs`
4. copy all the data from the 1TB back
5. enjoy Linux

Answer (score 0):

"I'm worried that I'll loose the data" - make sure you back it up.

In one Linux install that I did (many years ago). I had a single boot drive plus two more in a raid array.  I accidentally selected the wrong drive to format and install the system on. Started formatting one of the raid drives, and lost EVERYTHING on the raid array (striped for capacity / speed not redundancy).

Moral of the story - don't be like (the old) me.

If you're going to move to popos - you can still read a fat32 / ntfs drive.  It's just not great for writing to ntfs (unless you install the ntfs-3g package).

If I were you - backup.  If you can't do that - move everything to the 1tb drive shut down the computer and then unplug the 1tb drive, do the install and once you're happy and sure you're going to use POP OS.

Then plug in the 1tb drive again.  If you want you can mess with different filesystems, but I would say that comes after you've tested your new Pop OS home.